# Is it possible to call the Pom.xml from Outside the code script to Compile ,Run and Generate EAR Using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, ant, ear

We got a ANT project J2EE to convert in to Maven Project,For that ANT project generate the EAR file in which outside the code they will run the ANT script ,In the ANt script They mention Project location of the build.XML and target Tag to run and compile

Now similarly How to call the Pom.XML from Outside the code using  Maven script

Please guide me

Comment: You go to the directory of the `pom.xml` and start `mvn clean install`. It will automatically pick up the `pom.xml` from the directory it is running in.

Comment: Thanks for your response @JFMeier ,Whole project wont convert in to One EAR file ,It will Generate 2 jar ,1 war and 1 EAR .So for  one maven script (Outside the code ) Pom.xml should generate 2 jars ,Place in one directory  and another Maven Script  Pom.xml should generate 1 jar ,Place in one directory like that

Comment: You need to adapt your project to Maven. One `pom.xml` will not generate more than one artifact. You can construct a multi-module project, though, so that one build builds all the modules, and each module creates a jar/war/ear.

Comment: Okay,Can you please Provide me sample example for references

Comment: https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

Comment: Thank you  @JFMeier